# What's the difference between sysconfig/network-scripts and sysconfig/networking

Tags: linux, networking

I'm working on a CentOS release 6.3 machine. I have what look like networking config files in both /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts and /etc/sysconfig/networking. Why the duplication? Which set of files should I edit?

Comment: My first intuition is that one is used by the kernel (`/etc/sysconfig/networking`) and the other is used my the GUI.  But I need to verify this, or maybe somebody else can.

Answer (score 0):

From most of my readings, the `/etc/sysconfig/networking` config is used by the GUI and should not be edited by hand (if you open the file, I believe it even says that in comments).  The `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` is a carry over from the RedHat/Fedora for compatibility reasons.